# how to fix unreadable tooltips(hover) in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse version is:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200
```

ubuntu is: 14.04LTS

when I'm using eclipse, I want to check the declaration/definition of some fields/functions/classes(blabla), the background and text are all black

I tried
1) set the gtkrc

```
gtk-color-scheme ="base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#f07746\nselected_fg_color:#000000\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#E6E6FA\ntooltip_bg_color:#C0C0C0\nlink_color:#DD4814"
```

2) use gnome-color-chooser

[image]

[image]

but all of them don't work, are there any other workarounds?

Comment: Eclipse Mars [isn't ready](https://www.prahladyeri.com/blog/2015/12/eclipse-mars-not-ready-for-linux.html) for linux yet, it was just launched recently. Use `Kepler` instead, its stable and your gtkrc workaround will work with that.